# Django: static file not found

Tags: python, css, django

Running Debian on Virtual Machine guest inside Windows host. Set Bridged for adapter-type. Installed Django on the guest and using build-in `runserver` and built-in database for testing purposes.

Having simple files structure:

```
> ..
> templates
>   base.html
> static
>   css
>     base.css
> manage.py
> setting.py
> ..
```

File `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

File `base.html`:

```
{% load static %}
...   
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
```

Getting error, not found:

```
GET http://192.168.XX.XX:8000/static/css/base.css
```

`Debug` in `settings.py` is set to true (means static files should be surved). The link looks correct. Now why doesn't this work?

**Edit:** looks like I forgot to run 'collectstatic'. Here is the output after running it:

[image]

**Edit2:**

```
EXTERNAL_APPS = [
  ..
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
PROJECT_NAME = 'fooproject'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, PROJECT_NAME, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Do you have read access?

Comment: @Sayse just added 664 to 'static/'. No change. Getting 404 (can this be related to read-access)?

Comment: What do your static settings look like?

Comment: did you collectstatic in the first place?

Comment: @ChristophBluoss I haven't run it explicitly. Didn't know one should do it. Updated problem after running `collectstatic`. The problem persists.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added to description the config related to static.

Comment: What is EXTERNAL_APPS?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `EXTERNAL_APPS` is just my custom variable that contains all django-related apps.

Comment: I have actually managed to make it work now! Thank you Christopher and Daniel - your comments actually helped me resolve this. I will post my answer with the steps I took.

Answer (score 8):

I have managed to resolve my problem with the help from ChristophBluoss and DanielRoseman. There were 2 problems:

1. I haven't ran `python manage.py collectstatic`.
2. The config missed crucial settings - `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

After adding those variables into `settings.py` file and successfully running `collectstatic` - everything worked fine.

P.S. One should read Django documentation more carefully. It wasn't stated clear enough for me that `collectstatic` is the mandatory thing.

**EDIT:** As DanielRoseman suggested `collectstatic` along with `STATIC_ROOT` is non-mandatory when `DEBUG` is set to `True`. I have tried to remove `staticfiles` and `STATIC_ROOT` - and it still works in my development environment. So `STATICFILES_DIRS` was the missing setting.

Comment: Hmm, collectstatic *isn't* required when you're serving static files in DEBUG. No doubt the problem was the missing STATICFILES_DIRS setting.

Comment: replacing `STATIC_ROOT` by `STATICFILES_DIRS` worked.