# Django won't serve my CSS or Javascript files -- static files

Tags: python, html, css, django

In `settings.py`, part of my code sets the static url.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My static files and folders are at `/home/myLinuxUsername/myApp/static/interactive-preview-dependencies`. That has the folders containing CSS, JS and images. It has the folders `images`, `scripts` and `stylesheets`.

My `urls.py`'s `urlpatterns` is like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # .. SOME CODE HERE .. 
    url(r'^interactive/$', interactive),
]
```

My `views.py` is like this:

```
def interactive(request):
    t=  get_template('interactive/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render())
```

And here's an example of how I try to load CSS on `interactive/index.html` **(updated)**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=static 'interactive-preview-dependencies/styles/main.css' %}">
```

When I run `python manage.py runserver` and go to `localhost:8000/interactive`, the terminal gives me this error: `"GET /static/interactive-preview-dependencies/styles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1757`

How do I fix this so Django finds and loads the CSS?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your app is called `myApp` and `interactive-preview-dependencies` is just a subfolder inside `/home/myLinuxUsername/myApp/static/`. According to [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/). You should reference it as

```
... href="{% static "myApp/interactive-preview-dependencies/styles/main.css" %}"
```

Comment: How would this work if I want to work on this on a different machine, especially a Mac or Windows? The absolute path won't be the same each time

Comment: It shouldn't matter. My point was that you should add the app name to the url.

Comment: Ah I see. I edited the relevant code, but I get this 404 error: `"GET /static/myApp/interactive-preview-dependencies/styles/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1781`. Looks like Django is looking in a different place now...

Comment: This answer should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40929708/2419215

Comment: I added `STATIC_ROOT` to `settings.py` (check updated question), then ran  `python manage.py collectstatic`. But I still get these 404s...