# Django doesn't load css file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I tried to search many posts about this problem and any one those couldn't solve my problem sadly and I couldn't understand on some points.This is the post.
[Django cannot find static files. Need a second pair of eyes, I'm going crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199029/django-cannot-find-static-files-need-a-second-pair-of-eyes-im-going-crazy)
I guess this is the most similar case with me and someone gave very nice answer for it, but it couldn't solve my problem :/

This is my file set

```
- beerlog  
 - beerlog
     - settings.py
     - ...
 - posting
     - urls.py
     - templates
         - posting
             - base.html
             - index.html
             - post.html
             - posting.html
     - static
         - posting
             - style.css
         - ...
 - static
     - registration
         - ...
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

/posting/templates/posting/base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Beerlog</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/posting/sytle.css">
        {% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class='headline'>Welcome to beerlog!</h2>
        <ul class="sidenav">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li>Welcome back {{ user.get_username }}!</li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={{request.path}}">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
```

/posting/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views


app_name = 'posting'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:post_id>', views.post, name='post'),
    path('posting', views.posting, name='postingform'),
    path('base', views.base, name='base')
]
```

/beerlog/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static, staticfiles_urlpatterns

from . import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('posting/', include('posting.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

I set static file same as django official documents like templates, templates work well but why css doeesn't work? Please help me guys :( Desperate

Comment: try to add this in your setings STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

Comment: bro did you imported css files through static function? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/posting/sytle.css">` ?? or just link?? use above comment for settings.py and `{% static 'path_to_css' %}` use this in place of `href="/posting/sytle.css"` and you css name is also wrong

Comment: @NoahLc I tried to do it, but they said I cannot contain STATIC_ROOT in STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: @khizarsyed I just used linked. I coulndn't use STATICFILES_DIRS due to the reason I said, but after I use with {%%}, it succeed. It seems like we have no choice on link href. Great thanks!

Comment: You have a typo in file name `sytle.css` instead of `style.css`.

Comment: why didnt you upvote it then

Answer (score 0):

Add `posting` folder into STATICFILES_DIRS as an additional (to the STATIC_ROOT) folder for collecting static files from:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'posting/static'),
]
```

In DEBUG=true it is enough to reach to those files. Before moving to DEBUG=false run `collectstatic` and files and folders from `posting/static` will be copied into STATIC_ROOT (you can try this right now).

Then refer your static files from template with `static` tag:

```
{% import static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/posting/style.css' %}">
```

If still not working - grab the URL from rendered template and try to open it manually, then check response status.

Also make sure you've added url patterns mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53591167/5921826) to make Django serve static files in DEBUG=true. Note, Django won't serve static files in DEBUG=false.