# Serving Django static admin files with debug off in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, django-templates

Per other posts on this subject, I followed the advice at https://bestprogrammingblogs.blogspot.com/2021/03/django-static-files-not-working-when-debug-is-false.html to serve static files when debug is false.

The site advises to make changes to Settings and URLs respectively

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

  

if DEBUG:

  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

else:

  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

  

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

and in URLs

```
re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}), 
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

For some reason, my local admin works but the AWS admin site does not. Do I need to tune anything on the AWS side to get this working? My environment variables don't explicitly have any static settings at the moment.

Comment: The article is misleading. Here is some description about [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076), here in the question mentioned how [url patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859511/django-doesnt-load-css-file/60861806#60861806) are supposed to be added. The best source is [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/) it mentions'em all, it's just fine. Follow the docs.

Comment: Note, on production Django is not supposed to serve neither static nor media files. And DEBUG on prod should not be True. Configure Nginx or other web server to serve them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that article is correct, you have to always define   `STATIC_ROOT`, you can also define `STATICFILES_DIRS`  if you want, both settings are not related to DEBUG status