# Django not loading CSS and JS files into browser

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am working on my first Django application. I built a template HTML file but cannot get the CSS and JS files to load when viewing on my localhost. I have consulted the Django official documentation but cannot manage to identify the issue. I have cleared the my browser's cache but it did not make a difference.

Settings.py

`{% load static %}` (included at the top of the script)

```
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'stltaxauctionmap/static')
]
```

templates/base.html - CSS

```
<link
      href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      href="{% static '/fonts/font-awesome.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-select.min.css' %}"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'css/jquery.slider.min.css' %}"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
```

templates/base.html - JS

```
<script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/smoothscroll.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/markerwithlabel_packed.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/infobox.js' %}"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-select.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.placeholder.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/icheck.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.vanillabox-0.1.5.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/retina-1.1.0.min.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jshashtable-2.1_src.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/tmpl.js' %}"></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.dependClass-0.1.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/draggable-0.1.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/jquery.slider.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/markerclusterer_packed.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'js/custom-map.js' %}"
    ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"></script>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

All URLs report 404:
[image: Picture of the errors in my browser]

Folders:

[image: Folder Structure]

note, I'm working on Windows.

Comment: `'\fonts\font-awesome.css'` wrong slash direction. Please show your folder structure and urls.py

Comment: also have a look at these answers [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66437690/django-html-template-cant-find-static-css-and-js-files/66439076#66439076) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590409/static-files-not-getting-loaded-in-django-python/53591167#53591167)

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Thank you for your suggestions. Below is my urls.py file. I am working on figuring out how to display my folder structure. 

'from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]'

Comment: urls.py needs edit similar to link number two

Comment: @IvanStarostin - Thank you for your suggestion. In the Django documentation it says "If you use django.contrib.staticfiles as explained above, runserver will do this automatically when DEBUG is set to True." DEBUG is set to True on my application. I assume this means that this fix won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your static settings are incorrect. Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    'static',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Do note that `BASE_DIR` gives you your project directory. So when you do `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject/static')`, it becomes `myproject/myproject/static`.

Comment: I tried this suggestion but it didn't work for me. This is the error that I received.

?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

Comment: Can you show me your directory structure?

Comment: I added a picture of the directory structure to the bottom of the post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have two static folder. The one outside should be working. Are the files shown missing in your post in the `stltaxauctionmap/static` or `stltaxauctionmap/stltaxauctionmap/static`?

Comment: .\stltaxauctionmap\stltaxauctionmap\static

Comment: That's your problem. You need to either move your static files from `./stltaxauctionmap/stltaxauctionmap/static` to `./stltaxauctionmap/static` or change the `STATICFILES_DIRS` to `stltaxauctionmap/static`.

Comment: The static folder in the root directory was created when I ran the collectstatic command.

Comment: I've changed the STATICFILES_DIRS to stltaxauctionmap/static, stltaxauctionmap/stltaxauctionmap/static and /static and none of these have worked for me. The full path to my static directory is C:\Django\stltaxauctionmap\stltaxauctionmap\static

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. Django is trying to pull files from outside of the virtual environment. I received this error when I was trying to run the server. 

File "C:\Users\BradS\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 46, in <module>

The path for my virtual environment is C:\Django\stltaxauctionmap\venv

How can I fix this?