# Django static don't read bootstrap javascripts file

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-5, django-staticfiles, django-static

When I import bootstrap css and js to django as static, css file connected and works, but js file show me error: "GET /static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 179.

My 'main.html'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    {% load static %}
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"
    />
    <!-- DataTables -->
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" />
    <!-- DataTables JS-->
    <!-- DataTable Scripts -->
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        {% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{message.tags}}">{{message}}</div>
        {% endfor %} {% endif %} {% block context %} {% endblock context %}
        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="container">
            <p>© Copyright {% now "Y" %} by <a href=""></a></p>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

My 'setting.py'

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

My project folder structure:

[image]

I need import css and js files as static, but django don't see js files, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static Files not getting loaded in Django Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53590409/static-files-not-getting-loaded-in-django-python)

Comment: It didn't help. I still get the error: "GET /static/datatables/js/query.dataTables.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1971

Comment: Is it correct that the url `/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` can be opened with no error now but some other URLs are broken?

Comment: I see you have included javascript files in head tag, try to move them all before closed body tag and let bootstrap file be first

Comment: Additionally, close the script tags like this: <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

Comment: This don't work, i replase <scripts> into all position, add </scripts> in end, create new project, but is don't help. I folow to all gide from youtube, but always the same error javascripts don't work. I download css and js from https://getbootstrap.com/ "Compiled CSS and JS".

Comment: Ok, I found the error, need to import a 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' file, instead of a 'bootstrap.min.js' file