# Django - Static files not found when DEBUG = True; all settings are correct according to docs

Tags: django

I have a project-level directory named `static` which contains various .css, images, and javascript files. My settings file contains:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
...
DEBUG = True
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/' # I've tried with and w/o this
STATICFILE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

My `urls.py` file contains:
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I've printed out `BASE_DIR` and it points to the correct directory. Yet, when I load my webpage, I receive this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css
```

This file exists, and it exists in exactly the location that Django is trying to access. Still, these files aren't found. I'm a bit at my wits end—the documentation has no information outside of what I've already done, and I've searched around for *hours*. All of the already-answered questions here regard `STATICFILE_DIRS`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928947/django-static-file-not-found) question, for example, points out that—when `DEBUG = True`—one doesn't have to run `collectstatic` and using `STATICFILE_DIRS` should suffice.

**Edit:** GOD DAMNIT. It's `STATICFILES_DIRS` and not `STATICFILE_DIRS`. That was my problem. -_-

Comment: Have you added the required settings to your urls? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: @art06 I have, yes (I edited that into my question), but I believe that this is only necessary if one doesn't have `django.contrib.staticfiles` in one's `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

In your urlpatterns, you have,

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
]  + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This means the static url must be the path, and the static root be the directory, but in your settings.py your static root is set to '/static/', which is wrong.

Here is what you can do,

1. Remove both STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILE_DIRS and also from the urlpatterns `+ static(...)`. And add load static in template , which will work correctly.
2. Add STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
       STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   then add `+ static(...)` part in urlpatterns.

Although you don't need to do the 2nd one. The first one will work fine.